# Is there a way to have global Flex 4 states (user roles)?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml, states

I am having an issue with flex states in my application. What I am looking to do is on creation complete of the application, obtain a user role guest/user/superUser (based on username and password) from a server, then set the state client side based on that information. My .mxml classes need to include certain graphic elements based on that state. I am running into the issues of including elements based on the states defined at the Application level of the project. I am trying to avoid having to define the states in each .mxml file that needs it.

I feel that this is possibly something easy that I am overlooking or maybe there is a better way to do this. Any examples input is very helpful.

I know that this returns the current state

```
Application.application.currentState;
```

but I am looking to almost "populate" the

```
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="state1"/>
</mx:states>
```

of every .mxml file from the states defined in the Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for dynamic states - [here](http://polygeek.com/2010/08/31/adding-states-at-runtime/) is your solution (The first two states – `default` and `big` - are added at compile time. The third state `Bang-a-Gong` is added at runtime):

```
private function init():void {
    // Create a new state and give it a name.
    var stateBang:State = new State();
    stateBang.name = 'Bang-a-Gong';

    // Set the overrides with an array of AddChild, AddItems,
    // RemoveChild, SetEventHandler, SetProperty, and SetStyle
    stateBang.overrides =
        [ new SetProperty( btn, "label", "Bang-a-Gong" ),
          new SetProperty( btn, "height", "150" ),
          new SetProperty( btn, "width", "300" ),
          new SetStyle( btn, "fontSize", "22" ),
          new SetStyle( btn, "fontWeight", "bold" ),
          new SetStyle( btn, "color", "#FF0000" ) ];

    // Add our new state to the available states of this component.
    this.states.push( stateBang );

    // Just for kicks lets add a transition for this state.
    var transition:Transition = new Transition();
    transition.toState = 'Bang-a-Gong';

    // Create a new transition effect.
    var resize:Resize = new Resize( btn );

    // Create an composite effect, either: Sequence or Parallel.
    var sequence:Sequence = new Sequence();

    // Add our resize effect.
    sequence.addChild( resize );

    // now add our composition effect to the transition we created.
    transition.effect = sequence;

    // Push our new transition into the transitions array for this component.
    this.transitions.push( transition );
}
```

In another case, if I understood in right way, you should create some Object in **main** application, and access it from all child components via `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication`.

If you want to change child states, you should have some instance with already defined states as minimum in one place, and later copy them, to child components, but what sense if they are all custom logic?

So, let me know, if it helps.

Comment: FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.yourObject.isSuperuser==true